# Intermittent AWS Lambda Invocation Failures with Azure Speech Synthesis using Serverless Framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure

I'm facing a peculiar issue while trying to use Azure Speech Services for speech synthesis in an AWS Lambda function. My setup involves wrapping the speakTextAsync call in a promise to use it asynchronously within my Node.js Lambda function. The function's purpose is to synthesize speech from text using Azure's Speech SDK and then process the audio further. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```js
const synthesizeSpeech = async (text, synthesizer) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Promise started");
        synthesizer.speakTextAsync(text, (result) => {
            console.log("speakTextAsync callback");
            if (result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
                console.log("Resolving promise");
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                console.log("Rejecting promise - synthesis failed");
                reject(
                    new Error(
                        "Speech synthesis failed: " + result.errorDetails
                    )
                );
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("Rejecting promise - error");
            reject(new Error("Speech synthesis error: " + error));
        });
    });
};
```

I am deploying the function using the Serverless Framework and have enabled observability features. The function is supposed to handle varying lengths of text for synthesis. However, I'm encountering intermittent issues where the Lambda invocation sometimes ends prematurely without any apparent reason. When this happens, the only log I see is "Promise started", indicating that the promise was initiated but not resolved or rejected.

The warnings I receive through the Serverless Framework's observability tools are as follows:

```json
{
    "source": "serverlessSdk",
    "type": "WARNING_TYPE_SDK_USER",
    "message": "Invocation closed without handler providing response for the invocation",
    "code": "HANDLER_NO_RESPONSE"
}
```

Curiously, the function does work at times, especially for longer texts, which suggests that execution time limits are not the cause of the issue. This intermittent failure is puzzling because the logs suggest that the function sometimes does not progress beyond the promise initiation.

I'm looking for insights or solutions to ensure consistent function execution and to understand why these intermittent failures occur. Could it be related to how the promise is handled, or is there something specific about AWS Lambda's execution environment that might cause the Azure Speech SDK's speakTextAsync function to behave inconsistently?